# How to schedule a campaign in mailchimp api v3?

Tags: mailchimp

I am trying to schedule a campaign using v3 of the MailChimp API but I can't see any method to do this on the API docs.

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/overview/

Does anyone know how if scheduling is possible on v3 yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To send a mail to a list, first you need to create a list and a campaign.

If you have already created those, you can send scheduled mails with HTTP request to below address.

```
https://SERVER.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/CAMPAIGNID/actions/schedule
```

**SERVER**: The server that MailChimp assigned you to, you can learn that by logging in. Your dashboard url will be something like https://us6.admin.mailchimp.com/

In above case, *SERVER* is **us6**.

And these are the requested parameters from MailChimp v3 Documentation.

**Request body parameters**

**schedule_time**

- Type: Schedule_time
- Title: Schedule Time
- Read only: false

The date and time in UTC to schedule the campaign for delivery.

**timewarp**

- Type: Boolean
- Title: Timewarp
- Read only: false

Choose whether the campaign should use Timewarp when sending. Campaigns scheduled with Timewarp are localized based on the recipients’ time zones. For example, a Timewarp campaign with a schedule_time of 13:00 will be sent to each recipient at 1:00pm in their local time. Cannot be set to true for campaigns using Batch Delivery.

**batch_delivery**

- Type: Object
- Title: Batch Delivery
- Read only: false

Choose whether the campaign should use Batch Delivery. Cannot be set to true for campaigns using Timewarp.

Comment: Could you please put the documentation link of this?

Comment: how can one specify the time? I am also interested in the documentation

Comment: This answer states it is not available for the api v3 https://github.com/shahriarhossain/MailChimp.Api.Net/wiki/Schedule-your-Campaign

Answer (score 0):

a bit late to the party on this one, the full link is (http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/#action-post_campaigns_campaign_id_actions_schedule), also as I couldn't find complete code, here is a simple sample using (https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net):

```
public bool CampaignCreate(string campaignName, string subject, string emailText,
        string emailSender, string emailSenderName, DateTime sendTime,
        int templateID, string listID, ref string campaignID)
    {
        MailChimpManager mgr = new MailChimpManager(_apiKey);
        try
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(campaignID))
                CampaignExists(campaignName, out campaignID);

            // convert to utc and round up to nearest 15 mins
            if (sendTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc)
                sendTime = sendTime.ToUniversalTime();

            sendTime = sendTime.RoundUp(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));

            Models.Campaign newCampaign = new Models.Campaign();
            newCampaign.Id = campaignID;
            newCampaign.Type = CampaignType.Regular;
            newCampaign.Settings = new Models.Setting();
            newCampaign.Settings.Title = campaignName;
            newCampaign.Settings.SubjectLine = subject;
            newCampaign.Recipients = new Models.Recipient();
            newCampaign.Recipients.ListId = listID;
            newCampaign.Settings.FromName = emailSenderName;
            newCampaign.Settings.ReplyTo = emailSender;
            newCampaign.Settings.TemplateId = templateID;

            newCampaign = mgr.Campaigns.AddOrUpdateAsync(newCampaign).Result;

            campaignID = newCampaign.Id;
            ContentRequest content = new ContentRequest();
            content.Html = emailText;

            mgr.Content.AddOrUpdateAsync(campaignID, content);

            mgr.Campaigns.ScheduleAsync(newCampaign.Id, new CampaignScheduleRequest()
            { ScheduleTime = sendTime.ToString("o") } );

            mgr.Campaigns.SendAsync(campaignID);

            return (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(campaignID));
        }
        finally
        {
            mgr = null;
        }
    }
```